# Simple Where Exists vs. In

Tags: sql, sql-server

I for the life of me can't see what I'm missing here but can someone point out to me why the first query doesn't do what I want, but the second one works fine?  I know the queries aren't exactly the same, but they should return the same 20 rows and they do not.
(query fill find the top 20 most common items in a single table)

```
    select distinct
             rx.drug_class
        from rx
        where exists
        (
            select top 20    
                     rx2.drug_class
                    ,COUNT(distinct rx2.pat_id) as counts
                    ,RANK() over(order by count(distinct pat_id) desc) as rn
                    from rx as rx2
                    --when the line below is commented out 
                    --this subquery gives the correct answer
                    where rx.drug_class = rx2.drug_class
                    group by rx2.drug_class
        )
```

This one works fine

```
select distinct 
        rx.drug_class
        from rx
        where rx.drug_class in 
        (
            select top 20 rx.drug_class
                from rx
                group by rx.drug_class
                order by COUNT(distinct pat_id) desc 
        )
```

The where clause in the Exists subquery isn't working, what gives?

Comment: are you sure commenting out `where rx.drug_class = rx2.drug_class` makes it work. Removing that link to the main query converts your Exists clause to  `EXISTS (SELECT * FROM rx)`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Even though you're assigning a row number for the first query, you still need to `ORDER BY` this row number:

```
where rx.drug_class = rx2.drug_class
group by rx2.drug_class
order by rn
```

Also, I'm assuming that this is just a simplified example, because the following would work just as well:

```
select top 20 rx.drug_class
from rx
group by rx.drug_class
order by COUNT(distinct pat_id) desc
```

EDIT:

Your `EXISTS` also won't work because you're limiting the set to matching rows in inner `SELECT` to rows in the outer set before you perform your counting... so the row will always exist in the`top 20` count in that case.

The `IN` works because it is one set of counts for all rows... the `EXISTS` fails because the counting is being done for each individual row in the outer set... so every row in the outer set is in the top 20 counts when those counts are limited to only the outer row's `drug_class`.

Comment: Why is that?  If I comment out the where that has the refernce to the outer query get the result set in order

Comment: I ran the same query with order by rn appended and I'm still getting the same result set.

Comment: I asked because I'm at a loss why the `exists` subquery isn't working. :)

Comment: My guess would be that it orders the inner query by `drug_class` in order to do the where logic comparison with the outer dataset where if you don't do this comparison it leaves it in the current ordering which would be by Count(Distinct pat_id) because it needed to do this for the `Rank` computation.

Comment: @wootscootinboogie just because you run the subquery on its own and it returns the data in a certain way does not mean it will do so when optimized as part of a larger query, or even that it will do so tomorrow when data changes, or statistics change, or you apply a hotfix, or enable a trace flag, etc. If you expect and want the TOP to be applied in a certain order, ***add an ORDER BY clause***. Without it, you are telling SQL Server that TOP can be applied in any old way it pleases.

Comment: @AaronBertrand Now that you mention it, I'm pretty sure I read in the SQL Server bible that you should always use `order by` then you use `top` :/

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know `EXISTS` clause just returns **TRUE** or **FALSE**. So, if EXISTS 20 rows from the subquery it means **TRUE**, not a filter as with the `IN` clause.